# PFTableViewController Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] When trying to delete

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting this error when deleting an image from my PFTableViewController. I've done an extensive search yet from what I can tell the code in commitEditingStyle is correct. Can anyone help?

```
import Foundation

class profileImageTableViewController:PFQueryTableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var MenuViewButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var addImageButton: UIBarButtonItem!
     let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "ProfileImages"
    self.textKey = "pImage"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}

// Define the query that will provide the data for the table view
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "ProfileImages")
    var userid = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId
    query.whereKey("userid", equalTo: userid!)
    query.whereKey("imageType", notEqualTo: "profileThumb")
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    return query

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self
    //println( myStruct   )
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "imageCropSegue"{
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? profileImageCropView {
            if let profileIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                var index = NSIndexPath(forRow: profileIndex, inSection: 0)
                var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! profileImageCell
                println(destination.profileImageView)
                destination.profileImageView.image = cell.profileImageView.image //currently generates an error (separate issue)
            }
        }

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileImages") as! profileImageCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = profileImageCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "profileImages")
    }
    var iType = object["imageType"] as! String

    //println(iType)
    if iType == "profile"{
        cell.profileImageButton.hidden = true
    }

    var file:PFFile = object["pImage"] as! PFFile
    cell.profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: file.name)
    cell.profileImageView.file = file
    cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground(nil)
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        let objectToDelete = objects?[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
        objectToDelete.deleteInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                self.loadObjects()
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }
    }

}

@IBAction func addImageTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if(self.objects?.count < 5){
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.imagePicker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
    }else{
        var alert = UIAlertController()
        self.presentViewController(alert.isNotification("Max images reached", buttonText: "ok", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        var data:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 0.5)
        var imageFile = PFFile(name: "profileimage.jpg", data: data)
        //imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        //imageView.image = pickedImage
        var myObject = PFObject(className: "ProfileImages")
        myObject["authorised"] = false
        myObject["userid"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId!
        myObject["imageType"] = "gallery"
        myObject["pImage"] = imageFile
        myObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success:Bool,error:NSError?) -> Void in
            self.loadObjects()
        }

    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

When I run the simulator the image gets deleted from parse but as soon as that happens I get the error.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxds5-29-lhIR0I3MGswdFE1LUU/view?usp=sharing

Here is the breakpoint at the loadObjects()

Comment: Post the full error please.

Comment: This is the full error.  2015-07-08 22:32:23.374 Gdate[78459:7789885] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44.2/UITableView.m:1623

Comment: It's not. I need the FULL error.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's the only error I'm seeing in the console. This is my first time using Xcode, is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: If you're actually not seeing a stack trace, the execution may have stopped at a point indicated in the code editor. Also, you'll see a stack trace on the left. Try interpreting them. If you need help with that, post them.

Comment: I've just tried running it again. The execution doesn't stop, the app continues to run so no stack is being generated. So when I delete a row the error is shown and the row is still in the table. If I navigate to a different view and back the row is gone (as the row had been successfully deleted from Parse). The error seems to come from when self.loadObjects() is being called.

Comment: Use break points to figure out the exact line in your code. You're very likely using wrong methods to update the table. Also post all relevant pieces of code, `loadObjects()` too.

Comment: I've just updated the thread to include the full code. loadObjects() is a PFQueryTableViewController method and is a BFTask.

Comment: Check what thread the block containing `loadObjects()` is executed on. It has to be the main thread.

Comment: I've added a link to a screen shot showing the threads at the loadObjects() breakpoint.  I can't see anything there that pertains to loadObjects()

Comment: I found the syslog for the simulator Here is the link to running the build and up to the point where I delete a row.  Here is a link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxds5-29-lhIODFWa1VfMWVabkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try using `reloadData()` instead of `loadObjects()`.

Comment: Tried this and although the error went away the row was still in the tableview. so I added tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) before reloadData() and guess what! The error came back! I'm wondering if this is a bug with PFQueryTableViewController?

Comment: Please read up more on deleting rows from table views. You're very likely doing it wrong. I'm sorry, but I cannot be of more help to you, unless I have all your code in hand. [Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) something you should read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Couldn't find an answer to this. In the end I ended up using the standard UITableView which deletes rows flawlessly without errors.

I would have thought that PFQueryTableViewController was created to make it easier using Table Views with Parse but surprisingly I was able to do the same with UITableView with hardly any extra code.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer above as correct for others? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.

Finally, I realized I had forgotten to remove 'objectToDelete' from 'objects' BEFORE reloading the tableView.